# How to map a List to a Set while applying a method(Java to Kotlin code conversion)?

Tags: kotlin, code-conversion

I have this code snippet in Java (this is an MCVE; actual code is more complex but has exact same issue):

```
enum StatusEnum { A, B, C; }

[...]

final static Set<String> names = Arrays.asList(StatusEnum.values())
        .stream().map(StatusEnum::name).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

IntelliJ gave me the following automated conversion to Kotlin:

```
    internal val names = Arrays.asList(*StatusEnum.values())
        .stream().map<String>(Function<StatusEnum, String> { it.name })
        .collect<Set<String>, Any>(Collectors.toSet())
```

This unfortunately has compile errors:

- Interface Function does not have constructors
- Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Collector!>! but Collector!>! was expected
- Unresolved reference: it

This is my very first attempt at converting some code to Kotlin. I have reviewed the [Functions and Lambdas section of the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html). Still not clear what's going on here or how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Kotlin methods instead of Java streams:

```
val names = StatusEnum.values()
    .map { it.name }
    .toSet()
```